# bind to an input on form

Tags: data-binding, angular

What i'm trying to do, is get the value of an `input` on my form and affect it to a variable on my `Typescript class`, here is my template :

```
<form [ngFormModel]="form" (ngSubmit)="save()">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>
            Action
        </legend>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="label">Label</label>
            <input ngControl="label" type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
```

For example here i want to get the value of the input called `label` when the user save the form and simply affect it like this :

```
export class ActionFormComponent {
    form: ControlGroup;
    _label: any;
    constructor() {

    }

    print() {
        this_label = this.form.label;
        console.log(this._label);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ngModel` does what you want:

```
<input ngControl="label" type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="label">
```